# Как будет правильнее?

Tags: синтаксис, падежи, предлоги

Щи ИЗ квашеной капусты или щи С квашеной капустой?

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (галка напротив выбранного ответа).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Правильно: щи из квашеной капусты.

ЩИ, мн. Жидкое кушанье из рубленой капусты или щавеля, шпината . Щи из крапивы. Зелёные щи (из шпината, щавеля и т. п.). Свежие щи (из свежей капусты). Кислые щи (из квашеной капусты). Суточные щи (из квашеной капусты, выдержанные в печи в течение суток после приготовления).

Щи с квашеной капустой - неточное выражение, так как предлог С обозначает сопутствующий предмет, а капуста для щей - ингредиент основной, определяющий. Да и фонетика  такого сочетания неудобна для произношения.

Comment: Большое спасибо!